# Using HTACCESS to redirect to specific page if Query in URL does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm looking to make .htaccess redirect to a new URL if there is NO query string attached to the original URL. For example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/Pricing/
```

should redirect to

```
www.mywebsite.com/newpricing/
```

if there is NO query attached to the /pricing/ url.

If there is a query string attached to /pricing/ such as:

```
www.mywebsite.com/pricing/?query
```

it should redirect to

```
 /pricing?query and NOT /newpricing/
```

In Summary:

```
www.mywebsite.com/pricing/?query goes to www.mywebsite.com/pricing/?query

www.mywebsite.com/pricing/ goes to www.mywebsite.com/NewPricing/
```

EDIT:

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/pricing/$ /newpricing
```

I've also tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^pricing/?$ /newpricing [NC,R=301,L]
```

neither seem to be doing the job. I've verified my mod_rewrite is enabled, and verified my `<directory>` structure is setup properly.

and it doesn't quite work. What am I missing?

Comment: `Is this possible with HTACCESS?` Almost any type of redirect is. What have you tried?

Comment: @panamaJack thanks for your response - I edited the post with what I have already attempted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^pricing/?$ /newpricing [NC,R=301,L]
```

The left URL in a htaccess RewriteRule never starts with a `/`

Comment: Hi @croises thank you for your response - I added this, and I'm actually starting to suspect that our mod_rewrite is not enabled via apache.

Comment: I just checked and our mod_rewrite is enabled via apache terminal.. not sure why this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you try to clear the browser cache, or with other browser ?

Comment: Hello, yes - I tried with a clear cache, and in an incognito window, and with a different browser. /pricing/ still loads fine and does not forward properly to /newpricing/.

Any other suggestions? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: sorry , forgot to tag you in my above response. I added some additional information in the OP.